# Update image-files in a specific directory

Tags: c#

I have some Images in a folder. The images can be easily transferred from the First to the Second folder. So far, everything seems to be ok, but how to pass an image from the First directory to the Second directory which is identical to the image that already exists in the Second folder? In simple terms: How to update or overwrite the files in this Second folder? Many thanks in advance for your help!

```
string pathName = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\Second\";                   

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\"))
{                           
   if (!Directory.Exists(pathName))
   {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
   }

   string destFile = Path.Combine(pathName, Path.GetFileName(file));

   if (!File.Exists(destFile))
   {
       File.Move(file, destFile);
                                
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move method can have a third parameter a boolean to override

```
Move(String, String, Boolean)
```

Moves a specified file to a new location, providing the options to specify a new file name and to overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0

Or You can use File.replace() if the File exist in destination to save a backup of the deleted file.

```
public static void Replace (string sourceFileName, string destinationFileName, string? destinationBackupFileName);
```

it will be like this

```
string pathName = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\Second\";                   

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\"))
{                           
   if (!Directory.Exists(pathName))
   {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
   }

   string destFile = Path.Combine(pathName, Path.GetFileName(file));
   string backupFile = 'Some place to backup the deleted image'.

   if (!File.Exists(destFile))
   {
       File.Move(file, destFile);                           
   }
   else
   {
       File.Replace(file, destFile, backupFile);
   }

}
```

you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.replace?view=net-5.0 for documentations

Comment: Great! This works for me. Thank you very much Oscar : )

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

I forgot, that method Move has third parameter `bool` overwrite. You can use it

```cs
 File.Move(file, destFile, true);
```

You will find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_Move_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)

You can use `File.OpenRead`, `File.OpenWrite` and `stream.CopyTo` methods for this task

```cs
if (!File.Exists(destFile)) 
{
      File.Move(file, destFile);
}
else 
{
      using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(file))
      using (var desStream = File.OpenWrite(destFile))
            sourceStream.CopyTo(desStream);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Anton. I get an error message every time... No overload for method Move takes 3 arguments. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @Mike19 It depends on what target framework you use. I thought that is the latest one: .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5 because due to docs, this method is supported for such versions. It would be helpful if next time you will define which target framework you use

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I use the NET. Framework 4.7 (Windows Application). Thank you for your valuable hint, Anton!